# Calling Hyperledger Fabric QSCC from user provided chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm looking for some example chaincode that calls the query system chaincode (QSCC) to get the details of a past transaction.

Comment: What fabric SDK are you using?

Comment: Good question.  Which ever SDK is needed if at all?  This isn't a client making the call as I know the answer there.  This is from within a chaincode.  An example in Java, JavaScript, or Go would be enough.